# Web api expand error 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Include'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

this is my model:

Exercise:

```
 public class Exercise
    {


        public int ExerciseId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Muscle:

```
public class Muscle
    {


        public int MuscleId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ExerciseAndMuscles

public class ExercisesAndMuscles
    {
        #region Properties

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //each exercise hits muslce by some percentage
    public int PercentageByWhichMuscleIsHit { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Navigational properties

    public int MuscleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Muscle Muscle { get; set; }


    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Exercise Exercise { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is FluentApi configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ExercisesAndMuscles>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.Exercise)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ExerciseId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ExercisesAndMuscles>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.Muscle)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MuscleId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I've added these two lines in TestDatabaseContext

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Here is my WebApi

```
public class ExerciseAndMuscleController : ApiController
    {
        readonly TestDatabaseContext _databaseContext = new TestDatabaseContext ();
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IQueryable<ExercisesAndMuscles> Get()
        {
            return _databaseContext.ExercisesAndMuscleses.Include( m => m.Exercise).AsQueryable();
        }
}
```

And when I try to query like this:

```
http://localhost:23758/api/ExerciseAndMuscle?$expand=Exercise
```

I get these errors:

```
{"$id":"1","$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"'object' does not contain a definition for 'Include'","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__b.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"}
```

And error without include and Lazy loading enabled is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your method like this:

```
[Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions= AllowedQueryOptions.Supported | AllowedQueryOptions.Expand)]
public IQueryable<ExercisesAndMuscles> Get()
{
        return _databaseContext.ExercisesAndMuscleses;
}
```

Web API should be able to translate the expand, of course Web API only supports expand in the nightly builds.

Comment: Now it wokrs, thanks :) May I Ask why that line was necessary ?

Comment: Well I think that the supported queryable options don't include expand nor select and if you are trying to use one of them you have to specify them.