# Breeze & EFContextProvider - How to properly return $type when using expand()?

Tags: entity-framework-5, breeze

I am using Breeze with much success in my SPA, but seem to be stuck when trying to return parent->child data in a single query by using expand().

When doing a single table query, the $type in the JSON return is correct:

`$type: MySPA.Models.Challenge, MySPA`
[image: without Expand]

However if I use expand() in my query I get the relational data, but the $type is this:

`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary 2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]]`

[image: with Expand]

Because of the $type is not the proper table + namespace, the client side code can't tell that this is an entity and exposes it as JSON and not a Breeze object (with observables, entityAspect, etc.).

At first I was using my own ContextProvider so that I could override the Before/After saving methods. When I had these problems, I reverted back to the stock EFContextProvider<>.

I am using EF5 in a database first mode.

Here's my controller code:

```
[BreezeController]
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    // readonly ModelProvider _contextProvider = new ModelProvider();
    readonly EFContextProvider<TestEntities> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<TestEntities>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Challenge> Challenges()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Challenges; 
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }       
    public IQueryable<ChallengeNote> ChallengeNotes()
    {       
        return _contextProvider.Context.ChallengeNotes;
    }
}
```

Here's my BreezeWebApiConfig.cs

```
 public static void RegisterBreezePreStart()
  {
      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "BreezeApi",
          routeTemplate: "breeze/{controller}/{action}"
      );
  }
```

Is there a configuration setting that I am missing?

Comment: Please show both relevant types in your EF model and your client side query... and whether you have any breeze.NamingConvention set. Also take a look at the Breeze DocCode sample, there are several examples of "expand" shown there.

Comment: At this point, I'm bypassing the Breeze client libraries - as you can see from the images above, this is about the response from the server.

![image for my model](http://www.volorecovery.com/images/capture.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try "expanding" on server side? Is it needed to do expand on client side? I tried to do expand before but failed for me as well, did some research and decided I'd rather place it on server:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Challenge> ChallengesWithNotes()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Challenges.Include("ChallengeNotes"); 
    }
```

This should be parsed as expected. On client side you would query for "ChallengeNotes" instead of "Challenges" and you wouldn't need to write expand part.

Comment: This worked as expected (though I've not tried client side yet) -- I thought (and told by @Jay Traband) that by using expand() on the client this effectively do the same. It was appealing to me that I could do all these "projections" on the client without have to make custom methods for all my queries. I still may have done something to foobar it.

`http://localhost:53644/breeze/data/ChallengeNotesInfo?$inlinecount=allpages`


My method:
` [HttpGet]
  public IQueryable<Challenge> ChallengeNotesInfo()
  {
   return _contextProvider.Context.Challenges.Include(x => x.ChallengeNotes);
  }`

Comment: You should be able to do the select on the client. Something is likely amiss with your model but we can't tell because you're not showing us everything. You know $expand really does work. There is something wonky on your server. You also have stuff there that I don't understand such as removing the XML formatter and the [Query] attribute; these spook me.

Comment: What other information would I need to show? The StackOverflow engine didn't show my image to the model, but puts it as a link instead. The XML part of the config was to force JSON results - I get the same results with or without that. I can execute the query with "ChallengeNotesInfo" (calls the server-side include), but Breeze doesn't seem to want bring in the Notes. My parent object is coming across just fine, but is showing challengeNotes[] as having zero entities. The metadata shows the Association and navigationProperty. http://www.volorecovery.com/images/capture2.png

Comment: Regarding the [Queryable] attribute - It stemmed from this same issue as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047449/web-api-expand-error-object-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-include . Without it I get this error when doing expand(): "ExceptionMessage":"'object' does not contain a definition for 'Include'","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException"

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the problem is due to your use of the `[Queryable]` attribute.

You must use the `[BreezeQueryable]` attribute instead!

See the [documentation on limiting queries](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller#limiting-query-options).

> We are aware that Web API's `QueryableAttribute` has been deprecated in favor of `EnableQueryAttribute` in Web API v.1.5. Please stick with `BreezeQueryable` until we've had a chance to write a corresponding derived attribute for `EnableQuery`.  Check with the documentation for the status of this development.